# Model selection using a standard p-value approach

Tags: logistic, anova, model-selection, p-value

I need to perform model selection using a standard p-value approach. Using logistic regression we would like to compare the following models:

```
Y =       A + B + C + D
Y = A*B + A + B + C + D
Y = A*C + A + B + C + D
Y = A*D + A + B + C + D
```

I performed the following analysis in R:

```
first  <- glm(Y~G+N+E+C,     family="binomial")
second <- glm(Y~G*N+G+N+E+C, family="binomial")
third  <- glm(Y~G*E+G+N+E+C, family="binomial")
fourth <- glm(Y~G*C+G+N+E+C, family="binomial")

summary(first)
summary(second)
summary(third)
summary(fourth)

anova(first, second, third, fourth, test="Chisq")
```

However, I think I do not have the right output here for a model selection based on p-values?

```
anova(first, second, third, fourth, test="Chisq")
# Analysis of Deviance Table
# Model 1: Y ~ G + N + E + C
# Model 2: Y ~ G * N + G + N + E + C
# Model 3: Y ~ G * E + G + N + E + C
# Model 4: Y ~ G * C + G + N + E + C
# Resid. Df | Resid. Dev | Df | Deviance | Pr(>Chi)
# 1   595   |  609.90    |                     
# 2   594   |  609.90    | 1 | 0.000169 |   0.9896
# 3   594   |  609.81    | 0 | 0.087775 |        
# 4   594   |  609.90    | 0 | -0.085001|
```

So, how to perform a model selection here, using a standard p-value approach?

Comment: Why do you "need to perform model selection"? This is almost never a good idea, (see: [why-is-variable-selection-necessary](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18214//18245#18245). It is certainly a bad idea using p-values (see: [algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836//20856#20856)).

Comment: Hi, It's just an assignment for school here. I also need to argue why p-values are a bad idea, so you helped me out here! Thanks

Comment: That sounds good, @Sophie. If this is a school-assignment, you need to add the `[self-study]` tag. Note that our policy is special in this situation; please review our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) & the [self-study wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), & let us know what you've done already & where you're stuck.

Comment: Hi, I have the analysis performed, but I don't know wether I performed it correctly... Can I post my R-script, Output and interpretation as a question, and add [self-study] or/and [homework]? Or is that not acceptable here?

Comment: There is no `[homework]` tag anymore, just add the `[self-study]` tag, & understand that we will treat this specially as noted at the links I provided above.

Comment: Like this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68622/perform-model-selection-using-bayes-factors-based-on-the-bic-statistic

Comment: Please don't open a new question, @Sophie. Just add the `[self-study]` tag to *this* one.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be possible to formulate these models as a nested structure?

First you would have a model like

```
Y=A*B+A*C+A*D+A+B+C+D
```

which is `H1`, and then

```
Y=A*B+A*C+A+B+C+D
```

which is `H0`.

Now you could do a Likelihood-Ratio test which is `-2*logLik(H0)+2*logLik(H1)` and is distributed as a $\chi^2$ with $k+p-k$ degrees of freedom where $p$ is number of extra parameters in the `H1`. If the result is large then you can say that it is not proper to use the `H0` model, `H1` is needed to explain variation in the original data (seen in the extra deviance which increases if second largest is used versus largest model).

This could be done in steps: first take largest model as `H1`, and second largest as `H0`; in the next step (if `H0` is rejected) you will take second largest model as H1 and third largest model as H0. And so on...

Comment: Hi, I only need to compare the models as specified above, which means that I have got non-nested models. I need to use a standard p-value approach, only one I could think about here was the Chi-square. Which means that I can only compare model 1 with all the others, but not model 2 with model 3 for example. However, the statistics favor model 1 with p-values above .72. But than the question remains, is this the best way to perform model selection using a standard p-value approach?