# Hierarchical Categories as Input Features

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-bayesian, categorical-encoding, data-preprocessing

I have a regression problem. Two input features describe a category and subcategory. For illustrative explanation, let's consider we speak about *city* and *district*.

Some more details about the regression problem: 39000 observations, 104 cities, each 1-17 districts. 5 additional demographical variables (age, salary, gender, marital status, education level). Trying to predict the number of children of a given person (from given city, district, age, salary, ....). In some districts, we have only 1 record

**The question**: Is there any specific method how to represent the nested categories for machine learning?

Important comments:

- Plain application of one-hot encoder to city-district pairs will not work as lots of combinations are very rare in the data.
- Still, not willing to ignore the information about districts completely.
- If doing just logistic regression, a hierarchical Bayesian model could help. However, what about xgboost or neural networks?

Non-specific attempts so far:

- To do one-hot encoding for both higher (city) and lower hierarchies (city-district) and then apply standard feature selection methods.
- To combine the above with explicit filtration of very rare combinations (say at least 5 examples).

Comment: Can you tell  us some more details? Many cities with many districts within each one? You could look at multilevel models, maybe mixed models.

Comment: Yes, many cities, each with multiple districts. The district is specified by city name and district name.

Comment: Added. How to combine mixed effects with a neural network?

Comment: Have a look at this paper? https://aclanthology.org/2020.ecnlp-1.10.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As a start I would go for a random effects model with districts nested within cities, and then for each district a random intercept. Then the few districts with only one or very few observations should not be a problem. With 39000 observations and only a few covariates I would just use them all, avoid feature selection, see for instance [Why is variable selection necessary?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18214/why-is-variable-selection-necessary). Spline variables such as salary and age, and use relevant interactions!

You seem to want some flexible model, like a neural network? I'm not sure what much sense that make with 39000 observations, start first with flexible linear mixed models and evaluate the results. But there **is** an R package [Buddle](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Buddle/Buddle.pdf) for neural networks with random effecs, and [google gives a lot of hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=neural+networks+with+random+effects&oq=neural+networks+with+random+effects&aqs=chrome..69i57.12182j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).